# map 2D python array in parallel

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multicore

I can scatter the pixels in an image according to a 1D map of tuples containing the old x,y coordinate of each pixel

Is there a way to do this faster such as using multiple CPU coords or otherwise?

```
i=0
for x in range(1080)
    for y in range(720)
        result_img_arr[x][y] = input_img_arr[map_tuples[i]]
        i+=1
```

input_img_arr - An image array with the shape (1080, 720, 3)

map_tuples - 1D array of tuples with length (1080*720) containing x,y the coordinates to read from input image

Comment: The code-blocks are missing the colons (`:`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about parallel-processing, but using a `list-comprehension` should definitely improve the speed. Something on the lines...

```
result_img_arr = [[map_tuples[y + x*720] 
                       for y in range(720)] 
                           for x in range(1080)]
```

Answer (score 0):

autojit with numba should speed that up considerably. And if that's still not enough you can take a look at pyopencl, but that can be a bit complicated to get right.